# Kill a process group

Tags: c, linux, unix, process

I have a process tree as P1 ⟶ P2 ⟶ P3 ⟶ P4 ⟶ P5 (so P2 is child for P1 and P3 is child for P2 and so on).

- Process P1 and P2 belong to same process group.
- Process P3 and P4 and P5 belong to other process group.

In process P1, we know the process group of P3, P4 and P5 (it is the value P3) and we are sending the SIGKILL to this process group. using `kill(-P3, SIGKILL)`.
The expectation is this will kill P3, P4 and P5 but not P2 but the observation is that P2
also got killed.
I have a two questions here:

1. Why is P2 getting killed?
2. What would be the exit status of P2 we will be getting in P1.

Comment: How do you know that P3, P4 and P5 are in a separate process group, and how did you set the process group for them?  On the face of it, the system disagrees with you and thinks P2 is in the same process group as P3 et al.  A [Short, Self-Contained, Correct (Compiling) Example](http://sscce.org/) would help.  The exit status of P2 reported to P1 would be `WIFSIGNALED(status)` true and `WTERMSIG(status) == SIGKILL`.  How do you know the process group of P3 in P1?

Comment: Which system calls are you using?  `setsid()`, `setpgid()`, `setpgrp()`, `tcsetpgrp()`, or something else?

Comment: I am using setpgid() to set the common process group for P3,P4 and P5.P3 will do fork() and exece of P4 and same for P5 which will make all of P3,P4 and P5 into the same process group. Although P3 is a child for P2 but after calling setpgid() it will move into different process group.

Comment: You need to show the code.  There are too many ways this could be written for us to be able to guess what you're doing.  Do you check the return values from `setpgid()`?  Did you validate the process groups with `getpgid()`?  How does P1 get to know the process group (or even PID) for P3?